# Is it possible to change replace datasource Dynamically in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some `LINQ` statements which make some queries in a database. Only the data source is different, otherwise the `where` clauses are the same. 
I only want to maintain the `where` clause in one place. Can this method be merged to one method?. See example of what I want.

I have this code:

```cs
    private void GetUsers(IReadOnlyCollection<Users> totalUsers, bool useDatabase)
    {
      if(useDatabase))
    {
        var usersList = datalayerModel.Where(x =>
                       x.CompanyId == 1 &&
                        x.EmployerId == 1 &&
                       x.EmployeeId == 1 &&);

    }
    else
    {
        var usersList = totalUsers.Where(x =>
                      x.CompanyId == 1 &&
                        x.EmployerId == 1 &&
                         x.EmployeeId == 1 &&);
    }
}

var usersList = (list or datalayer).Where(x =>
                    x.CompanyId == 1 &&
                    x.EmployerId == 1 &&
                    x.EmployeeId == 1 &&);
```

The comment from juhar directed me in the correct direction. I ended up with solution: 
(datalayer.Model.Users has type System.Data.Entity.DBSet)

```
var sourceUsers = users == null ? datalayer.Model.Users : users.AsQueryable();

var usersList = sourceUsers.Where(x =>
                    x.CompanyId == 1 &&
                   x.EmployerId == 1 &&
                   x.EmployeeId == 1 &&);
```

Comment: `datalayerModel` is an `IDataContext`?

Comment: I guess you could assign the list or db set to a common variable of type `IQueryable<T>` by using `AsQueryable` on the list.  Assuming that it's a list of the entity type.

Comment: What is the type of `datalayerModel`? Of `totalUsers`?

Comment: Datalayer model is DataContext. I'm using Entity Framework

Comment: @user2480218 There are 3 answers and did you get time to see if any of those meet your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can affect both sources to a pivot variable which you would use later for the query

```
private void GetUsers(IReadOnlyCollection<Users> totalUsers, bool useDatabase)
{
    IEnumerable<Users> userSource;
    if(useDatabase)
    {
        userSource = datalayerModel;

    }
    else
    {
        userSource = totalUsers;
    }

    userSource.Where(x =>
                         x.CompanyId == 1 &&
                         x.EmployerId == 1 &&
                         x.EmployeeId == 1);
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, depending on the type of dataLayerModel, you may have to transform one of the source to match the other.

If `dataLayerModel` is `IQueryable`, then you have to do:

```
private void GetUsers(IReadOnlyCollection<Users> totalUsers, bool useDatabase)
{
    IQueryable<Users> userSource;

    if(useDatabase)
    {
        userSource = datalayerModel;
    }
    else
    {
        userSource = totalUsers.AsQueryable();
    }

    userSource.Where(x => x.CompanyId == 1 &&
                          x.EmployerId == 1 &&
                          x.EmployeeId == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `totalUsers` and `datalayerModel` is of type `IUsers` or `Users`, you can create an Expression like this

```
private static Expression<Func<IUsers, bool>> Condition
{
    return x.CompanyId == 1 &&
                     x.EmployerId == 1;
}
```

and Instead of swapping the data source you can reuse the common where condition like this

```
if(useDatabase){ return datalayerModel.Where(Condition); }
else { return totalUsers.Where(Condition); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep your where clause logic in one place and reuse it, you can create a class with [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).
Your implementation would be basically like this

**Extension method class with custom methods**

```
public static class LINQExtension
{
    public static double CustomWhere(this IEnumerable<YourDataType> source)
    {
        if (source.Count() == 0)
            // your logic validation here
        source.Where(x =>
                     x.CompanyId == 1 &&
                     x.EmployerId == 1 &&
                     x.EmployeeId == 1 &&);
    }
}
```

**Call your extension method class**

```
private void GetUsers(IReadOnlyCollection<Users> totalUsers, bool useDatabase)
{
    if(useDatabase))
        var usersList = datalayerModel.CustomWhere();
    else
        var usersList = totalUsers.CustomWhere();
}

var usersList = (list or datalayer).CustomWhere();
```

I hope this helps.